# How can I make a calculated number show a certain decimals behind the . in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, decimal

Hello I am trying to make some calculation show 2 decimals in JavaScript.
Here are my files

This is te code from the form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="number" name="aantal" id="a"     onkeypress="validate(event)" onkeyup="calc()" value="<? aantal(); ?>"> BTC =
<input type="text"   id="x" name="roundedfield" onkeypress="validate(event)" onkeyup="calcback()" value="<?php valuta(); ?>" 
<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
```

And here is the piece of code in JavaScript

```
function calc() {
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var ticker = document.getElementById("b").value;
    document.getElementById("x").value = txt1 * ticker;
}
function calcback() {
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("x").value;
    var ticker = document.getElementById("b").value;
    document.getElementById("a").value = txt1 / ticker;

}
```

Comment: use [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), i.e. `1.5.toFixed(2)` gives `"1.50"`

Comment: How would i add this in the function for example calc()
Like
var total = document.getElementById("a").value;
total.toFixed(2)

is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

[toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) will do what you need it to do.

```
function calc() {
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var ticker = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var result = txt1 * ticker;
    document.getElementById("x").value = result.toFixed(2);
}

function calcback() {
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("x").value;
    var ticker = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var result = txt1 / ticker;
    document.getElementById("a").value = result.toFixed(2);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but after I added that line it doesnt calculate anymore :(

Comment: You would have had to do it for both "ticker" and "txt1". Since you're actually calculating the values after retrieving both of them. Sorry about that. I've made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = txt1 * ticker;
document.getElementById("x").value = result.toFixed(2);
```

Was the solution